# Elm JSON decoding into list of objects: BadBody error

Tags: json, http, elm

I'm super new to elm and I am currently having problem with parsing a HTTP response, which is in the form of JSON. It looks something like this:

```
[
{
    "title":"Songs, Merry and Sad",
    "author":"John Charles McNeill"
},
{
    "title":"The Ambassadors",
    "author":"Henry James"
}
]
```

Basically, my web app sends a request to my backend, which responds with a JSON file as such. I have created this type alias:

```
type alias Book =
    { title : String
    , author : String}
```

In addition, here is my HTTP request:

```
search : Model -> Cmd Msg
search model =
  Http.post
    { url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/search"
    , body = Http.multipartBody [Http.stringPart "keyword" model.keyword]
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotSearch searchDecoder
    }
```

And here is my decoder:

```
searchDecoder : Decoder (List Book)
searchDecoder =
    Json.Decode.list bookDecoder

bookDecoder : Decoder Book
bookDecoder =
    map2 Book
        (field "title" string)
        (field "author" string)
```

Despite clearly stating expectJSON in my HTTP request, I get this BadBody error with the following message:

```
Problem with the value at json[0]:\n\n    {\n        \"title\": \"Songs, Merry and Sad\",\n        \"author\": \"John Charles McNeill\"\n    }\n\nExpecting a STRING
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. Help would be greatly appreciated since I'm super stuck here.

Comment: Your JSON decoders work fine on the data you've given, I couldn't reproduce a problem.  However, I *could* reproduce your error message if I changed `bookDecoder` to `map2 Book string (succeed "")`.  Therefore, I'd guess that either your Elm code needs recompiling, your browser page needs refreshing, you aren't running the decoders you think you are or the JSON data you get back from the server isn't as in this question.

Comment: What I do when I'm really stuck is to make a minimal example, including a minimal backend, that reproduces the problem. Start with your full code, and keep taking bits out till you have least possible amount of code that still reproduces the problem. It will take a while, but you will likely solve it before you have finished, and if you don't, you can post the minimal example on here and someone will be able to solve it for you.